# Is the Nikon 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6G AF-P DX lens compatible with the D7100?

Tags: lens, nikon, nikon-d7100

I have a Nikon D7100. Is the Nikon 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6G AF-P DX lens compatible with this body?

Are there images made with this lens & body combination available?

Comment: Thanx for the info.   I have just registered to day and still new at this but the info really helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can find which lenses are compatible with your Nikon camera on the Nikon Lens page: [Nikon D7100](http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/dslr/d7100/compatibility02.htm)

Finding images made with a particular lens can be challenging. I suggest you look at Flickr, on their [Camera pages](https://www.flickr.com/cameras/nikon/d7100/) as a start. From here you can examine images made with this camera, and search for tags or focal length to help narrow down to the particular lens. I don't see a way to search the EXIF directly unfortunately.

Comment: Here’s another good source for information about AF-P lens compatibility specifically: https://www.nikonimgsupport.com/eu/BV_article?articleNo=000035705&configured=1&lang=en_GB

Comment: The problem with only depending on the owner's manual is that lenses introduced *after* the manual is written won't be included on the list in the manual.

Comment: The same is true of web pages that have not been updated since the introduction of AF-P lenses.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this obscure compatibility list from Nikon USA](https://www.nikonusa.com/Images/Learn-Explore/Photography-Techniques/2011/Which-Nikkor-is-Right-for-You/Media/NIKKOR-lens-compatibility-chart.pdf), the D7100 has *Limited Compatibility* with AF-P lenses. The D7100 may require a firmware update if it is not already using the latest firmware version for that camera.

What *[limited compatibility](https://www.nikonimgsupport.com/eu/BV_article?articleNo=000035705&configured=1&lang=en_GB)* means for the D7100 is:

- You will not be able to disable VR with AF-P lenses that include VR. AF-P lenses do not have a VR on/off switch on the lens and the camera apparently doesn't have the hardware capability to turn it off from the camera.
- You will not have a menu item with the option to enable/disable "Manual focusing" by turning the focusing ring when AF is enabled. (Newer Nikon cameras include such an option in the camera's menu.)
- If the lens is retracted when the camera is turned on, you will get a "lens not detected" error. You must have the lens in the non-retracted position before powering on the camera.
- The lens will set the focus position to infinity each time the camera's meter is  activated. This means when you have activated metering and focused on a subject, normally by half pressing the shutter button, if you release the shutter button after focusing and metering times out, the lens will not hold the position to which it is focused when metering is once again activated.

All AF-P lenses have "focus-by-wire" focusing, even when using "manual" focusing. The focus ring is not mechanically connected to the lens' focus mechanism. Instead the focus ring is an electronic switch that sends a signal to the camera which, in turn, sends a signal to the lens' AF motor to move the lens by an amount determined by how far you have moved the focus ring.

From Thom Hogan's [review of the AF-P DX Nikkor 70-300mm f/4.5-6.3G ED VR](http://www.dslrbodies.com/lenses/nikon-lens-reviews/nikkor-zoom-lens-reviews/nikon-70-300mm-f45-63-af-p.html):

> The current list of full compatibility is D500, D3300, D3400, D5300, and D5500 (but make sure that you’re using the latest firmware).  The following cameras have no way to set VR and may change focus position if the camera’s meter goes inactive (requiring you to re-obtain focus): Df, D5200, D7100, D7200, D750, and D810. **All other Nikon DSLRs should be considered completely incompatible with this lens. Further note that this is a fly-by-wire lens, so while it may appear to mount on those other Nikon DSLRs, you can’t focus the lens manually, thus the incompatibility warning.**

Searching Flickr for "[D7100 18-55mm AF-P](https://www.flickr.com/search/?text=D7100%2018-55mm%20AF-P)" only returns four photos and one video. Two of the stills are pictures *of* the lens, not taken with the lens. [A third is a two side-by-side shots](https://www.flickr.com/photos/fdfotografie/41452580502/in/photolist-TuU4Np-24BcAkq-KNDwHm-26a2iZQ-KwMkL9). The left half was taken at 34mm and the right half was taken at 23mm with the Nikkor AF-P 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6 VR using a D7100.

Based on the EXIF info combined with an "AF-P" tag, [this image](https://www.flickr.com/photos/eusufzaibd/33801215663/in/photolist-TuU4Np-24BcAkq-KNDwHm-26a2iZQ-KwMkL9) appears to have been taken with the combination in which you are interested.

The description of [this video](https://flic.kr/p/24BcAkq) indicates it was shot using a D7100 and Nikkor AF-P 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6 VR lens.